# How do I show there exists a real matrix T such that

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the following matrices :
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 &-1\\1 & 2 & -1 \\-1&-1&4\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &-4\\0 & 5 & 4 \\-4&4&3 \end{bmatrix}$$
How do I show there exists a real matrix T such that $B=T^tAT$? And what is that matrix?
I notice that the given matrices are symmetric, but how do I use that fact?

Comment: Is $A$ typed correctly? It is not symmetric as is.

Comment: I edited it @BrianFitzpatrick I am sorry you were right

Comment: If you can diagonalize the matrices in an orthogonal basis, then you only need to show that the two resulting diagonals are congruent (i.e, they satisfy the condition you mentioned) which should be a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

Two matrices $X$ and $Y$ are **congruent** if there exists an invertible $Q$ such that $X=Q^\top Y Q$.

There is a great theorem that determines when two symmetric matrices are congruent.

**[Sylvester's Law of Inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).** Two symmetric $n\times n$ matrices $X$ and $Y$ are congruent if and only if the diagonalizations of $X$ and $Y$ have the same number of positive and negative elements.

A nice exposition on Sylvester's Law of Inertia, including a proof, can be found [here](http://palmer.wellesley.edu/~aschultz/w10/math416/coursenotes_and_handouts/coursenotes_100422.pdf).

It seems that you are given two symmetric matrices and asked whether they are congruent. Can you apply this result to solve your problem?

Comment: eigenvalues for A are -5,2,1 and for B are 9,-3,3 @BrianFitzpatrick

Comment: @user123,  $++-$ is called the signature for that class of congruent matrices.

Comment: eigenvalues for A are 5,2,1 and for B are 9,-3,3 @abel. Does that mean that since the signatures are not the same then they are not congruent

Comment: @user123, that is correct.